# Crontab to back up directory

Tags: cron

So I have this in my `crontab -e`

`0 0 * * * /opt/www/backup.sh`

And in the file, I have the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILENAME=$(date +%Y%m%d).tar.gz
tar zcf backups/$FILENAME f
```

The file is located at `/opt/www`

But the backup doesn't get created at all. If I run `backup.sh` manually, then it'll run and create the backup of the directory `f` as it should do.

I'm running Debian 7.8.

Comment: *It doesn't get created everyday* means that it is created on some days but not on the other, or that it does not get created at all?

Comment: At all. I should have worded it better, apologies.

Comment: So @Lambert is most probably right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current (working) directory is probably not set to /opt/www when the cronjob is started. You can set it in your script backup.sh before the `tar...` line by:

```
cd /opt/www
```

or you can use the full path in the tar line by:

```
tar zcf backups/$FILENAME /opt/www/f
```

I can also advise to use a full path for `backups/$FILENAME`

Comment: I didn't know that it run relatively.. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When `corntab` runs code, its running it from relative path starting from your home directory.

**Easy fix :** You can use absolute directory path (starting from `/`) in your script.

**Other method:** use 'path_dir' in your code for portability.

```
path=$(readlink -f $0)                                       
path_dir=${path%/*}
```